# Displaying a post issue php

Tags: php

So, I have this system where you can make a post. So, how it works is, there is an input field, whatever you type in the input field, and click post, it will send to the database as en entry and get posted. The post will be displayed. However, with my current system, after entering something in the input field, and clicking post, the entry gets sent to the database, but the post doesn't actually display. For it to display, you need to refresh the page again, which it displays then, and two entries go to the database.

I don't want this to happen. Right when the user enters text into the input field and clicks post, the post should display on the go, you shouldn't have to refresh for the post to be displayed, and only one entry should be sent to the database, not two. Now, I won't include my database connection and my insert statements, but here is the code to display the post:

```
<div class="textPost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    // all the displayed post content
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>
```

Insert Statement (post.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

// Making Connection To The Database

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "root";
$database = "feed";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $database) or die ("Sorry, we could not connect to the database");

// Posting System

if (!empty($_POST['postContent'])) {
  $post = $_POST['postContent'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (firstname, lastname, body, date_posted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  // nested if statement
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $firstname, $lastname, $post);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
} else {
  echo "";
}

?>
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? Please help.

Comment: You need to post more information. The page that does the insert could include the one that creates the table.

Comment: Ok. Check my edited question.

Comment: Add a require_once to post.php to include the page that displays the table. You might get a warning about restarting the session - but you can sort that out.

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: post.php can deliver the table from the file that has "textPost" in it using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: To show posts without refresh use ajax calls with jquery

Answer (score 0):

**table.php**

- queries the database and delivers a table - the `"textPost"` file
- lets the user add another row and sends it to *post.php*

**post.php**

- inserts the data into the database
- uses [require_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to include table.php which will display the updates. `require_once 'table.php';`

Comment: Ok, so what do we do in table.php? What would the code be?

Comment: I used **table.php** to refer to the page that creates the HTML with the table